# Inserting elements from a sorted array into a BST in an efficient way

Tags: arrays, binary-search-tree

I am struggling with this exercise:

> Given a BST T, whose nodes contain only a key field, a left and right field and a sorted array A which contains m keys. Write an efficient algorithm which inserts into T any A's keys which are not already present in T. You must not apply the `InsertBST(T,key)` algorithm on single A's keys.

For example if the BST contains 1,3,4,5 and A contains 1,2,5,6, I have to insert 2,6 without using `InsertBST(T,2)` and `InsertBST(T,6)`.

This is what I tried:

```
Algo(T,A,index)
     if T != null then
          Algo(T->sx,A,index)
          p = NewNode()
          p->key = A[index]
          if T->key > A[index] then
               T->sx = p
               index = index + 1
          else if T->key < A[index] then
               T->dx = p
               index = index + 1
          Algo(T->dx,A,index)
```

But it inserts nodes at the wrong places. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, we can help you. What is the problem? You just copied the assignment, but didn't explain which problems you encounter when working on it. "Help me" is not a suitable question for this site. There must be a clear problem statement of the problem *you* have with solving the challenge. Show your efforts, your research, any code so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @trincot I have no idea how to solve this, since I can't loop on every A'keys and insert them if they are not already present

Comment: Write the code anyway, and try, even if it turns out not to be the most efficient -- you should have a go at it. Your question might get some attention if you show that you worked on it and really tried.

Comment: ...hint: use the fact that an in-order traversal of the BST will give you the node values in sorted order. Combine that with the given that A is also sorted. Use that tandem...

Comment: @trincot ok I will try soon

Comment: @trincot I edited my post with my done

Comment: OK, are you really working with pseudo code, or do you have a target language in mind?

Comment: @trincot pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following issues with your attempt:

1. In each recursive call you are going to insert a node. So for instance, also when you reach the first, left-most leaf. But this cannot be right. The first node insertion *may* have to happen completely elsewhere in the tree without affecting this leaf at all
2. There is no check that `index` runs out of bounds. The code assumes that there are just as many values to insert as there are nodes in the tree.
3. There is no provision for when the value is equal to the value of an existing node in the tree. In that case the value should not be added at all, but ignored.
4. In most languages `index` will be a local variable to the `Algo` function, and so updating it (with `+ 1`) will have no effect to the `index` variable that the caller has. You would need a single `index` variable that is shared across all executions of `Algo`. In some languages you may be able to pass `index` by reference, while in other languages you may be able to access a more global variable, which is not passed as argument.

### Algorithm

The algorithm to use is as follows:

Perform the inorder traversal (as you already did). But keep track of the previously visited node. Only when you detect that the next value to be inserted is between the values of those two nodes, you need to act: in that case create a new node and insert it. Here is how to detect where to insert it. Either:

1. the current node has no left child, which also means the previous node (in the inorder sequence) is not existing or is higher up the tree. In this case the new node should become the left child of the current node
2. the current node has a left child, which also means the previous node is in the left subtree and has no right child of its own. In that case, add the new node as right child of the previous node.

### The Sentinel idea

There is a possibility that after visiting the last node in inorder sequence, there are still values to insert, because they are greater than the greatest value in the tree. Either you must treat that case separately after the recursive traversal has finished, or you can begin your algorithm by adding a new, temporary root to your tree, which has a dummy, but large value -- greater than the greatest value to insert. Its left child is then the real root. With that trick you are sure that the recursive logic described above will insert nodes for *all* values, because they will all be less than that temporary node's value.

### Implementation in Python

Here is the algorithm in Python syntax, using that "sentinel" node idea:

```py
def insertsorted(root, values):
    if not values:
        return root  # Nothing to do

    # These variables are common to all recursive executions:
    i = 0  # index in values
    prev = None  # the previously visited node in inorder sequence

    def recur(node):
        nonlocal i, prev  # We allow those shared variables to be modified here
        if i < len(values) and node.left:
            recur(node.left)
        while i < len(values) and values[i] <= node.value:
            if values[i] < node.value:
                newnode = Node(values[i])
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = newnode
                else:
                    prev.right = newnode
                prev = newnode
            i += 1
        prev = node
        if i < len(values) and node.right:
            recur(node.right)
    
    # Create a temporary node that will become the parent of the root
    # Give it a value greater than the last one in the array
    sentinel = Node(values[-1] + 1)  
    sentinel.left = root
    recur(sentinel)
    # Return the real root to the caller
    return sentinel.left
```